# Mysql join optimize where clause

Tags: mysql

There are two tables in Mysql5.7, and each one has 100,000 records.
And each one contains data like this:

```
id  name
-----------
1   name_1  
2   name_2  
3   name_3  
4   name_4  
5   name_5
...
```

The ddl is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Now I execute following two queries to see whether the latter will be better.

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE * 
from table_a a inner 
join table_b b on a.name = b.name 
where a.id between 50000 and 50100;
```

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE * 
from (
    select * 
    from table_a 
    where id between 50000 and 50100
) a 
inner join table_b b on a.name = b.name;
```

I think that in the former query, it would iterate up to 100,000 * 100,000 times and then filter the result by where clause; in the latter query, it would first filter the table_a to get 100 intermediate result and then iterate up to 100 * 100,000 times to get final result. So the former would be much faster than the latter.
**But the result is that both query spends 1.5 second. And by using explain statement, I can't find any substantial differences**
Does the mysql optimize the former query so that it executes like the latter?

Comment: The query planner can tell that the two queries are equivalent.

Comment: Yep, this is what the DBMS optimizer is for. It is very easy to see that the two queries are equivalent, so the optimzer comes up with the same plan. There are othe situations where it is harder for the optimzer to spot that two queries do actually the same, and it may come up with different plans then.

Comment: If you're going to execute queries on `name` it should have a key.

Answer (score 1):

For `INNER JOIN`, `ON` and `WHERE` are optimized the same.  For `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`, the semantics are different, so the optimization is different.  (Meanwhile, please use `ON` for stating the relationship and `WHERE` for filtering -- it helps humans in understanding the query.)

Both queries can start by fetching 100 rows from `a` because of `a.id between 50000 and 50100`, then reach into the other table 100 time.  But how it has to do a table scan because of the lack of any useful index.  So 100 x 100,000 operations.  ("Nested Loop Join" or "NLJ")

The solution to the slowness is to add

```
INDEX(name)
```

Add it at least to `b`.  Or, if this is really a lookup table for making "names" to "ids", then `UNIQUE(name)`.  With either index, the work should be down to 100 x 100.

Another technique for analyzing queries is

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'Handler%';
```

It counts the actual number of rows (data or index) touched.  100,000 (or multiples of such) indicate a full table/index scan(s) in your case.

More:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Joins are always faster than sub-queries, so try to use joins instead of sub-queries wherever you can to speed up the process. Whereas in this case, both the queries are equivalent.

Another way to optimize the query would be using partitions. When using partitions, mysql will directly go to the partition according to your specified query which will reduce the time spent on other unrelated records.

Comment: When `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT` are used, there are cases where a "derived" table (that is, a subquery in `FROM` or `JOIN`) may run a lot faster.